# Non-Closed Logic?

Tags: logic

Our logic is usually called "closed", i.e. if there's some formula/propostion F then its negation ~F is also a formula/proposition.

Could there be also a non-closed logic, i.e. a logic where F is a formula/proposition, but ~F is not?

Comment: Point (3) seems unrelated to points (1) and (2).

Comment: @Pippen Here is an example for you. In category theory they have morphisms (maps) and the operation of composition on them. But one can only compose morphisms when the source (domain) of one matches the target (codomain) of the other. Otherwise, the composition is not well-formed (undefined). If composition can be only partially defined, why not negation? One can declare that ~ can be applied to wffs of one sort, and produce another wff, but not to wffs of other sorts. For example, one can declare that wffs with ∃ in the prefix are not negatable, as in existential SOL.

Comment: Negating a logical proposition ipso facto makes a logical proposition, at least in the logic of human deductive reasoning, even though it is itself not closed in this sense.

Comment: Would you consider [seven-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaina_seven-valued_logic) to be closed by your definition? (Please read look at all the values carefully before answering.)

Comment: These are two different meanings of "closed". The first is purely syntactic and basically needed to define a [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language). The second meaning of "closed" is more subtle (and powerful) in that now you're allowed to rewrite the formulas in whatever way you want (using the  theory generated by the axioms) and as long as you can find some form that is in the language fragment then it's said closed (in this 2nd sense).

Answer (score 4):

I'll address points (1) and (2); point (3) seems unrelated (and frankly, too vague to admit an answer in my opinion).

Re: (2), there is unfortunately no standard definition of "logic" (or "logical system," or "formal system," or etc.). There are various different definitions employed in different contexts. One of the standard ones - the notion of a **regular logic** (see e.g. the end of [Ebbinghaus-Flum-Thomas](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387942582)) - does indeed require closure under negation, and so existential second-order logic (for example) is not a regular logic. But there are many other definitions floating around, including vastly more general ones.

Your argument in (1) that all logics have to be closed under negation seems to rest on the assumption that a logic should consist of *all meaningful expressions* in some context. Since every meaningful statement's negation is also meaningful (I think this is indisputable), this would indeed imply negation-closure. However, this sort of "expressive maximality" is *not* generally assumed. For example, we tend (to put it mildly) to consider first-order logic a logic, but it is clearly not maximally expressive since e.g. there is no first-order sentence corresponding  to finiteness.

Basically, when we talk about existential second-order logic as a logic, there is no tacit assumption that negations of existential second-order sentences need not be meaningful; rather, we're merely choosing to focus on a particular set of meaningful expressions, for whatever reason - either intrinsic interest or application in some way. It may help to observe that interesting *properties of* logics (broadly construed) need not be "negation-symmetric." For example:

- Every satisfiable existential second-order sentence has a countable model, but there are satisfiable universal second-order sentences without countable models.
- Every finitely-satisfiable set of existential second-order sentences is satisfiable, but there are finitely-satisfiable sets of universal second-order sentences which are not satisfiable.

So existential second-order logic has the downward Lowenheim-Skolem and compactness properties, while universal second-order logic doesn't. Together with its [game-theoretic analysis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-if/#FirOrdLogExiSecOrdLog), this points to existential second-order logic as being "meaningfully tamer" than its dual.

---

Incidentally, while I've absolutely taken a mathematical stance above, **this isn't something which should be thought of as purely mathematical**. For example, the standard adage "it's impossible to prove a negative" (ignoring its serious flaws) points to a fundamental difference in *nature of meaningfulness* between "purely existential" and "purely universal" claims. One can argue - at least in certain contexts - that some claims are "confidently affirmable but not confidently deniable." I would argue that what makes a logic "natural" is that we have some unifying idea of how its sentences are granted meaning, and while meaningfulness is preserved by negation the *type of* meaningfulness need not be.

Comment: What I meant was this: For any (formal or informal) system S who uses the symbol "~" as an operator on some expression of S it must hold that if p is an expression of S then also ~p is such. That's what I mean with closed negation, it's basically a syntactical theorem. Do you agree that any logic whatsoever needs this theorem? What is does philosophically: it prevents you from being able to refer to anything outside of what S allows (that is if we interpret "~" as what we call a negation).

Comment: @Pippen "Do you agree that any logic whatsoever needs this theorem?" No, since we haven't picked a definition of "logic." **As my answer says**, there are various definitions floating around, and some do require closure under negation while others don't. Some sets of sentences are closed with respect to negation, others aren't; which ones qualify as "systems" or "logics" will depend on the definition of "system" or "logic" being used.

Comment: Meanwhile, re: "What is does philosophically: it prevents you from being able to refer to anything outside of what S allows (that is if we interpret "~" as what we call a negation)": that seems like a total non-sequitur to me. I don't understand how $S$ being closed under negation has to do with referring to things "outside" $S$.

Comment: So you think there is a system possible where we define "~" as an operator to a legal expression of the system and then when we have such a legal expression p then ~p would not necessarily be also a legal expression in this system? That's what I fail to grasp because for me that's obviously impossible due to the syntactical rules.

Comment: @Pippen "that's obviously impossible due to the syntactical rules" **What syntactic rules exactly?** This all comes down to the tacit assumptions you're making about what constitutes a logic, which - again - are **not common** to all definitions used in the literature. There's nothing fancy going on here, it's just that some notions of "logic" allow for different conventions than you're expecting.

Comment: If S is not closed under negation then p could be a formula of S, but ~p could be not a formula of S. That means - first glance - that ~p could "talk" about outside of S. Of course it seems impossible since ~p needs S to "talk" at all.

Comment: @Pippen "If S is not closed under negation then p could be a formula of S, but ~p could be not a formula of S. That means - first glance - that ~p could "talk" about outside of S." I'm not really sure what that means, but in one sense at least that's right: there need be no expression in S which is equivalent to (the possibly-outside-of-S expression) ~p. But I have no idea what you mean by "Of course it seems impossible since ~p needs S to "talk" at all." You clearly have some preconditions for what constitutes a "system"/"logic"/whatever in mind, and those may indeed require negation-closure.

Comment: But since you haven't actually **stated** what those are, there's not much that can be said.

Comment: Does it matter which rules? If I construct a system S and say that S has some legal expressions X1, X2,... and that "~" operates on a legal expression then to me it's a must that if X23 is a legal expression then also ~X23, else "~" is simply redundant garbage.

Comment: @Pippen It clearly does, since existential second-order logic is not closed under negation but does, according to some definitions anyways, constitute a logic. "...  else "~" is simply redundant garbage" I don't agree at all. Rather, in something like existential second-order logic, negation is like *division*: sometimes it results in an expression within the system but other times it doesn't. There's no sense in which division is "redundant garbage" just because 1/0 doesn't make sense.

Comment: " If I construct a system S and say that ... "~" operates on a legal expression" It sounds like you're assuming here that ~ always transforms legal expressions into legal expressions (and, presumably, is interpreted as negation). If that's part of your assumption on S, then obviously S is negation-closed - you're basically building into your hypotheses on S exactly what you want to prove!

Comment: Last question to not overdo here: So in existential second-order logic it is possible that you have a wff formula p, but ~p is not a wff there?

Comment: @Pippen Yes, exactly. In existential second-order logic, negation is only a *partial* syntactic operation.